# How to authenticate with token (-u) in cURL call in PHP code?

Tags: php, authentication, curl, libcurl, php-curl

I'm having this call in my cmd that returns the corresponding response:

```
curl https://my-hostname-path/v -u {api_key}
```

where instead of `{api_key}` I'm sending a token linked with my account, example: `value_of_my_api_key`

Now I want to make the call in php by using `curl_setopt` commands. I'm having this code:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"https://my-hostname-path/v");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "api_key:value_of_my_api_key");
$out = curl_exec($ch);

print "error: " . curl_error($ch) . "<br /><br />";
print "output: " . $out . "<br /><br />";

curl_close($ch);
```

and got the error:

> error: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate

so what is the `curl_setopt` command that replaces `-u` and how to implement it in the php code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see any problems with the CURL call itself. My bet is that your server does not have the proper CA certificate to authenticate the SSL. You can store the CA on your server and use the `CURLOPT_CAINFO` option to validate it.

If you don't care about verifying the SSL certificate you can always add

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
```